# git flow hotfix naming / versioning

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, git-flow

When thinking about the git flow I face a problem when it comes to creating hotfix branches.

When using git flow (at least with SourceTree) it seems that the tagged version for a hotfix has to be determined right before committing/pushing anything. So if our current version is `1.2.0` and we want to fix a bug the next version tag will be `1.2.1`. But how do I know that `1.2.1` will not be taken by another hotfix before I will finish and push my fix?

Am I thinking wrong or is this a problem that developers should be aware of?

Answer (score 1):

In our team we use it this way:

1. Start a hot-fix with a specific self-descriptive name
2. Never finish it before it's been approved by QA team
3. Finish the hot fix
4. Manually create a tag with a version we need

On the step 3, yes, there will be a tag with name of the hot-fix. Usually we delete it, once everything is finished. The only thing we care at this moment is the version of new release and a proper history on the master.

Answer (score 1):

We struggled with this same conundrum and decided that while 1 hotfix overtaking another was a possibility it should be a rarity and there was a workaround.  A few things we considered:

1. Is it really a hotfix if it's going to be open long enough that it is likely for another hotfix to take priority?
2. Is it ok if there is a gap in our patch version numbers (i.e. 1.2.0, 1.2.2, 1.2.3)?  We decided this was ok.
3. As a workaround in the case that 1.2.2 needs to go out first, 1.2.1 can either be renamed to 1.2.3 or merged into a new 1.2.3 branch and then deleted.

Hope that helps.

Comment: As an aside you might consider this plugin for your CI server (we use TeamCity)  https://github.com/ParticularLabs/GitVersion